# I want to use facebook api to post into users wall using python/django

Tags: python, python-2.7, django-socialauth, socialauth, social-authentication

I am new in python/django.

I want to make an app by which I can post onto Facebook user wall using python/django and I have visited the [github](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) link and [this link](http://artandlogic.com/2014/04/tutorial-posting-to-facebook-from-a-django-app/). But still I don't understand how to post on users wall. I have created a app on [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com) and I have read the graph api. I have used the appsecret and appid also but still the problem exists. Is there is any specific tutorial for that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this is on Step 3 of your link. have you try to do the same ?

Comment: yes i have tried but i want to know that how to post on user wall by django admin